# Why do I feel centrifugal force If I move with constant speed on a turn?

Tags: forces, centrifugal-force

Title sums it up pretty much, I'm studying for my physics exam right now and I just can't wrap my head around this

Comment: Have you learned about changing reference frames and fictitious forces?

Comment: Constant speed is not always constant velocity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acceleration is the change in velocity $$\frac{d\vec v}{dt}$$. Importantly $\vec v$ is a vector, meaning that it has both magnitude and direction. So changing the direction of your velocity vector is indeed an acceleration. In uniform circular motion your velocity vector is not constant because its direction is changing, even though the magnitude stays the same.

Answer (score 2):

Because as the car turns around a corner it is forcing you away from your straight inertial path so your path has to curve with the car. As the seat, seat belts, or whatever part of the car you are touching curves away from your straight inertial path it applies pressure on you forcing you away from the straight line you would continue on if no forces were applied.